# Insert pre id as text inside given div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to obtain the shown div id and insert it in the given div as text, and change at the same time as the div id is shown and hide I'd like it to be compatible with all browsers

```js
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo) {
  var $els = $('pre[id^=' + selector + ']'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function() {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function() {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}
jQuery(function() {
  mostrarEsconder('moto1', 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer1">
  <pre id="moto1" class="position">
AA
</pre>
  <pre id="moto12" class="position">
BB
</pre>
</div>
<div id="consola">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell the output you are expecting?

Comment: I'm specting a text with the id name changing when the pre appears and disappears @PraveenKumar

Comment: Where does that text go, in `consola`?

Answer (score 0):

Get the ID with `$els.eq(i).attr('id')` and display it in `#consola`.

```js
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo) {
  var $els = $('pre[id^=' + selector + ']'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function() {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function() {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
      $("#consola").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}
jQuery(function() {
  mostrarEsconder('moto1', 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer1">
  <pre id="moto1" class="position">
AA
</pre>
  <pre id="moto12" class="position">
BB
</pre>
</div>
<div id="consola">
</div>
```